# If both A and B energized with zero phasing

Tags: electrical

If the electrical panel is energized from a  single 120 volt source such that A & B are zero phased, what happens if a 240 volt breaker(double pole breaker powering air conditioning) is turned to on position?

Answer (score 5):

Nothing will happen. The two poles are already tied together so a duplicate connection does nothing.

Comment: +1, your answer is 5 times shorter then some others and absolutely correct

Answer (score 4):

Nothing. The phases are already connected together before the panel. Connecting it a second time changes nothing.

Answer (score 3):

### Absolutely nothing

Since A and B are connected to the same leg, the load sees 0 volts across it, and thus does nothing whatsoever.  Note that if you have a mixed 120/240V load, bad things might happen if the 120V bits run but the 240V bits don't run.

Answer (score 3):

As already correctly stated in 3 other answers, nothing will happen on the 240V circuit.

However, questions like this don't come out of nowhere. This can't be about wiring up a building for a 120V utility supply, because then it would not have any 240V appliances. Generally this type of question means *backup power*, such as a generator or battery backup. With that *implied* question comes the following important things to consider:

- Interlock. This is a critical simple mechanical device to prevent utility power and backup power from connecting to the panel at the same time. That provides critical life safety for utility crews *and* prevents utility power from zapping your generator, both of which can happen without an interlock by somebody doing things out of sequence when switching between power sources.
- Inlet/Outlet - Normal plug-in loads are on outlets (a.k.a., receptacles). If you have a plug-in backup power source it *must* be on an **inlet** instead of an outlet. That prevents use of "suicide cords" and keeps things safe in a number of scenarios.
- MWBC - A Multi-Wire Branch Circuit is wired to a pair of breakers on opposite legs or a double-breaker and uses a shared neutral to feed two separate 120V loads. It is *possible* for an MWBC to have an overloaded neutral when fed from a power source that is providing the same power to both legs. It is *unlikely* because few 120V residential power sources will provide more than 20A - if they could provide more power they would normally split to the two legs and provide 240V power. But it is *possible* and MWBC loads in the panel should be checked to make sure this is not an issue.

Comment: *Well, my work is done here* :)